# Kivy Fix "Output of vertex shader 'frag_color' not read by fragment shader" message

Tags: python, kivy, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

When using any Kivy Screen transition based on the ShaderTransition, a message saying

```
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] program: <WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'frag_color' not read by fragment shader>
```

is outputted, and I would like to get rid of this message. I know that I can set the logger levels to turn off any message classified as `info` and below which would resolve this, but I'd prefer to not do that. I'd rather modify the necessary files to fix this message. So, I'm wondering what would need to be done to fix the `Output of vertex shader 'frag_color' not read by fragment shader` error.